# The "Add another item" button doesn't work with field groups

Tags: 7, ajax, javascript, entities

I am working on a site that uses a lot of horizontal field groups. I am having a problem where any fields that sit in a field group and have "unlimited" set for the number of entries is unable to use the "Add another item" button. The AJAX call is returning some JS settings but no HTML.

The fields themselves range from simple text fields to node references. If a field is not residing in a field group then it works fine.

I will point out that I am using Drupal 7 and field_group version 7.x-1.1.

It seems that the Drupal core is unable to properly identify which button was clicked and so has not idea how to respond.

Comment: I have the exact same problem here, when I click on Add another item for a multiple values field inserted in a fieldgroup, it does not work. Could you tell me if you found any solution for that (jQuery update? AJAX problem? PHP version?). Thanks.

Comment: Even i have same problem. "Add Another item" is working if i login as administrator,but is not working with user's id.I have given node edit permission to all registered users.Please can anybody help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

another option is to use the field_collection as described here: http://openconcept.ca/blog/mducharme/creating-multiple-value-field-groups-drupal-7

i'd like to see this in field_group to though - as the detour of making collections under 'structure' isn't as intuitive as under 'manage fields'

Comment: Even i have same problem. "Add Another item" is working if i login as administrator,but is not working with user's id.I have given node edit permission to all registered users.Please can anybody help me.